# TortoiseHG clone Issue

Tags: bitbucket, tortoisehg

I tried multiple times to clone my project but every time I received NOT FOUND ERROR: 255
[Please review the attached screenshot. Thanks you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzpON.png)

Answer (score 0):

Isnt `TortoiseHG` a `Mercurial` client. And you should not write `git clone` in the address field and most likely even not `https`.

Bitbucket stopped serving `Mercurial` projects, now it's only `git`.

I think you should try using Bitbucket's own git client.